# Yii 1 Pagination takes every params user inserted

Tags: yii

I have my pagination url set to 
www...com/category/detail.html?page=2

For which my code is,

```html
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Page', array('criteria' => array('condition' => 'status=1', 'condition' => 'category_id=' . $categoryObject -> id, 'order' => 'postDate DESC'), 'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 4,'pageVar'=>'page'), ));
$dataProvider->getData();
var_dump $dataProvider->totalItemCount;
```

I am getting the exact data counts and my pagination url seems working. I have my URL rule configured as

```html
'index'=>'site/index',
'contact'=>'site/contact',
'privacy'=>'site/privacy',
'sitemap.xml'=>'site/sitemap',
'<category:\w+>' => 'category/detail',
'<category>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'category/detail',
'<category>'=>'category/detail',
'<category:\w+>/<postTitle:.+>' => 'category/post',
'<category:\w.+>/<postTitle:.+>'=>'category/post',
```

my auto generated pagination URl are working fine but,
If I manually insert url something like
www......com/category/detail.html?Page_page&page=2
www......com/category/detail.html?Page_pizza&page=2

or any stupid things I can put they navigates to the page. 
Now, here I want to remove these extra parameters or I want my pagination url to be strict to
www...com/category/detail.html?page=2
and if I put any additional params I want an error page.

I have been working in this for 2 weeks and tried every possible ways I could.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ["params" property](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#params-detail) of the pagination to an empty array:

```
'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 4,'pageVar'=>'page', 'params' => array()),
```

This will avoid exclude any GET parameters from pagination links(if you need any included, add their name there).

To throw an error, you need to check for the parameters in your action.

```
// remove valid prameters from get array.
$arr = array_diff_key($_GET, array_flip(array('page', 'postTitle', 'category')));
// if still there are parameters left, throw an error.
if(count($arr) > 0) {
    throw new CHttpException('invalid parameter');
}
```